# Downloading jar with all dependencies from third-party Maven repo

Tags: maven, ivy

I want to download a library and all it's dependencies from third-party Maven repo. This command line `ivy -dependency com.fasterxml.jackson.core jackson-databind 2.9.10 -retrieve "lib/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"` works for Maven Central, how can I add extra resolvers for Ivy to search?

Comment: Why not use Maven dependency plugin?

Comment: I have no experience with `pom.xml` and basically need a standalone tool (which I actually found in form of Coursier)

Comment: What is the target build system for which you want all these files?

Comment: It's not a build system, I need to distribute a command line utility

Comment: But your command line utility is probably written in Java (if it has Java dependencies). How is it built?

Comment: It's written in Scala in built with sbt

Comment: Does sbt allow you to bundle an artifact with its dependencies? Maven has features for that.

Comment: It does. Though this particular utility depends on lots of Hadoop libraries so creating a fat jar would be quite painful